# Is there a tool that will crimp close the end the ribs on a metal roofing panels?

Tags: roof

I saw a building that had the exposed bottom edge of the ribs in the metal roofing panels crimped closed so bugs couldn't craw or fly up them. It was very neat/professional looking as if it had been done at the factory, or at least with a tool designed specifically for that purpose.

Comment: Would "metal roof closure strips" fit your needs?

Comment: Please go see it again and take pictures; then post them here.

Comment: Metal roofing comes in several different styles. Not sure what you're describing. Flattening corrugated roofing? Standing seam flat panel metal roofing? Ribbed flat panel metal roofing? Pictures would go a long way towards helping provide an answer as to the exact metal roofing panels and the way to finish off the eaves.

Answer (score 1):

Commercial standing seam roofs are systems. Very often they are fabricated with dedicated digitally controlled equipment from engineered design drawings. Eaves, soffits, and drips are likewise designed and shop fabricated. In the field, seaming is typically done with purpose specific tools.

All of which is a round about way of bringing home the idea that the infrastructure is outside the budget of most homeowners [as well as a great many residential tradespersons] and that off the shelf parts aren't readily available. Thus, it's not really a DIY sort of project for even the  skilled.